# detecting TCP/IP packet loss

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have tcp communication via socket code like :

```
public void openConnection() throws Exception
{
   socket = new Socket();
   InetAddress iNet = InetAddress.getByName("server");
   InetSocketAddress sock = new InetSocketAddress(iNet, Integer.parseInt(port));
   socket.connect(sock, 0);

   out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
}
```

and send method as :

```
synchronized void send(String message)
{
 try
 {
    out.println(message);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    throw new RuntimeException(this.getClass() + ": Error Sending Message: "
        + message, e);
 }
}
```

And I read from webpages that, TCP/IP does not guarantee delivery of packet, it retries but if network is too busy, packet may be dropped([link]).[1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-packet-dropping/index.html?ca=dat)

> Packets can be dropped when transferring data between systems for two key reasons:

- Heavy network utilization and resulting congestion
- Faulty network hardware or connectors

> TCP is designed to be able to react when packets are dropped on a network. When a packet is successfully delivered to its destination, the destination system sends an acknowledgement message back to the source system. If this acknowledgement is not received within a certain interval, that may be either because the destination system never received the packet or because the packet containing the acknowledgement was itself lost. In either case, if the acknowledgement is not received by the source system in the given time, the source system assumes that the destination system never received the message and retransmits it. It is easy to see that if the performance of the network is poor, packets are lost in the first place, and the increased load from these retransmit messages is only increasing the load on the network further, meaning that more packets will be lost. This behaviour can result in very quickly creating a critical situation on the network.

Is there any way, that I can detect if packet was received successfully by destination or not, I am not sure that `out.println(message);` will throw any exception, as this is non blocking call. It will put message in buffer and return to let TCP/IP do its work.

Any help?

Comment: That whole retransmission process is done in a different layer. You don't have access to it through Java. It's done for you.

Comment: But is it guaranteed that re transmission will occur and be successful? Can it not fail?

Comment: That's TCP for you. It will continue retrying (more or less). You would probably get a timeout error if it was not successful after a certain amount of time.

Comment: yes, about that timeout, where will I get that timeout? In java or somewhere else?

Comment: It will propagate to Java, yes. Check out the `Socket` javadoc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *TCP is designed to be able to react when packets are dropped on a network.*

As your quote says, TCP is design to react automatically to the events you mention in this text. As such, you don't have anything to do at this level, since this will be handled by the TCP implementation you're using (e.g. in the OS).

TCP has some features that will do some of the work for you, but you are right to wonder about their limitations (many people think of TCP as a guaranteed delivery protocol, without context).

There is an [interesting discussion on the Linux Kernel Mailing List ("*Re: Client receives TCP packets but does not ACK*")](http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/0106.1/1154.html) about this.

In your use case, practically, this means that you should treat your TCP connection as a stream of data, in each direction (the classic mistake is to assume that if you send n bytes from on end, you'll read n bytes in a single buffer read on the other end), and handle possible exceptions.

Handling `java.io.IOException`s properly (in particular subclasses in `java.net`) will cover error cases at the level you describe: if you get one, have a retry strategy (depending on what the application and its user is meant to do). Rely on timeouts too (don't set a socket as blocking forever).

Application protocols may also be designed to send their own acknowledgement when receiving commands or requests.

This is a matter of assigning responsibilities to different layers. The TCP stack implementation will handle the packet loss problems you mention, and throw an error/exception if it can't fix it by itself. Its responsibility is the communication with the remote TCP stack. Since in most cases you want your application to talk to a remote application, there needs to be an extra acknowledgement on top of that. In general, the application protocol needs to be designed to handle these cases. (You can go a number of layers up in some cases, depending on which entity is meant to take responsibility to handle the requests/commands.)

Comment: yeah, but my doubt is, where exception /error will be thrown because `out.println(mesaage)` is non blocking call, and it will return after sending the message not caring whether it reached destination or not?

Comment: Not sure what's around your code snippet, but this looks like blocking I/O (with an infinite timeout too). Anyway, you'd still get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP does not drop the packet. The congestion control algorithms inside the TCP implementation take care of retransmission. Assuming that there is a steady stream of data being sent, the receiver will acknowledge which sequence numbers it received back to the sender. The sender can use the acknowledgements to infer which packets need to be resent. The sender holds packets until they have been acknowledged.

As an application, unless the TCP implementation provides mechanisms to receive notification of congestion, the best it can do is establish a timeout for when the transaction can complete. If the timeout occurs before the transaction completes, the application can declare the network to be too congested for the application to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Code what you need. If you need acknowledgements, implement them. If you want the sender to know the recipient got the information, then have the recipient send some kind of acknowledgement.

From an application standpoint, TCP provides a bi-directional byte stream. You can communicate whatever information you want over that by simply specifying streams of bytes that convey the information you need to communicate.

Don't try to make TCP do anything else. Don't try to "teach TCP" your protocol.

Comment: I am not trying to teach TCP anything, instead trying to learn TCP. :P

Comment: You are. You have created a message. You are asking when that message has timed out. TCP has no idea what a "message" is (remember, *you* created this "message"). You are trying to teach it to be a message protocol that understands when things happen to messages. If you need your messages to be acknowledged or to time out, you have to code that. TCP doesn't know anything about application messages.